# How to set body background image as cover for ios devices

Tags: css, background-image

I have a div with background image and i set `background-size:cover` to make full width and height background image. but its not working in ios devices how can i set it for ios devices please help me

thanks

Comment: Try `-webkit-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: 100%;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `background-size: cover;` and not `background-image`. Also, you should be using `browser` prefixes as the property was released under CSS3 Specification<sup>1</sup>..

```
body {
   background-image: url(#);
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

<sup>1.</sup> [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Comment: @user2894216 I don't see any reason for not working, also, if you are expecting it to be responsive than you are wrong

Comment: how can i make it responsive

Comment: @user2894216 either use media queries and change dimensions, u n also try `background-size: 100% 100%;` but no fluid responsiveness

Answer (score 1):

*edit* - Updated Fiddle

I had a similar problem. I got my solution by setting a scroll attribute for background. Also be sure to set the parent container to 100% height and width. AdrianS has the right point for aiming at html to set 100% height and 100% width.

In the following code, I have a `header` class for the background image. Adapt it as you need.

Check out a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Bavc_Am/7L3gD/5/

Upvote if helpful please, I'm new here.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Full Page Image Header Area */

.header {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/800x800.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .header {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/800x800.png) no-repeat center center scroll; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User mkubilayk posted the solution the really worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari). The lifesaver whas the property below:

`background-attachment: scroll;`

Quoting:

> I have had a similar issue recently and realised that it's not due to
>   background-size:cover but background-attachment:fixed.
>
> I solved the issue by using a media query for iPhone and setting
>   background-attachment property to scroll.
>
> .cover {
>       background-size: cover;
>       background-attachment: fixed;
>       background-position: center center;
>
> ```
> @media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
>     background-attachment: scroll;
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I will provide can be seen [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). But with a minor change. This method is tested many times and for IE it has IE8+ support. You can see the full browser support in the link that I provided.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #Fallback-color;
  background: url(../images/image.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/image.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
  height: 100%;
}
```