# CSS background images resizing incorrectly on iPad and iPhone.

Tags: html, ios, css

My site's background image is resizing nicely in Chrome and Safari using background-size: cover, but when I go to test my website on an ipad or iphone, the CSS background image is really zoomed in and looks horrible. I've read lots of other questions on here relating to this and none have solved my problem.

HTML

```
<div class="background"> 

</div><!--background-->
```

.background has no container and is 100% width of the screen.

CSS

```
.background {
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background: url(css/img/strand.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: try this: width:auto;

Comment: Have you set a `viewport`? E.g: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Ruddy Yes I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @AndrewChappell I think you should take a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari).

Comment: I tried width:auto but it didn't work

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Adroid is rendering the background just fine.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I had the same issue, I used SCROLL instead of FIXED.

```
background-attachment:scroll;
```

Comment: After working on this problem for hours, this problem fixed my issue in seconds.  Thank-you!

Comment: Thank you very much. Can anyone explain why this works? Is it treating the barrel roll as a scroll?

Comment: works perfectly fine, I use fixed in desktop and scroll in mobile devices.

Comment: Two days trying to fix this, and this was the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the iPad's Safari is [downsampling](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ipad-3-benchmark-review,3156-5.html) images above the 1024px threshold. I had tried using `scroll` instead of `fixed` but that wasn't successful. [Other tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari) didn't work for me either.

I [solved this](http://leserservice.zeit.de/die-zeit-diese-woche/inhalt/?fullscreen) by splitting my originally-too-large 1600×1600 image into *two* images. Because of that, I was able to use two 1024px sized images and achieved an even better readability than before.

Maybe a workaround like that would work for you, too.