# Scaling images to 16:9 aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a `background image which is getting scaled,` but the problem is it is getting stretched and looking uglier when looked at smaller resolutions.

```
.bcg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Slide 1 */
#slide-1 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/bcg_slide-1.png'); 
             background-size: 100% 100%}
```

HTML Markup

```
        <section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
            <div class="bcg">
                <div class="hsContainer">
                    <div class="hsContent">
                        <h2>Hello1</h2>                         
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

If i use `background-size: 100% auto;` then its not `perfectly fitting the entire window`. Is there any solution to make the `background-image` inside a div perfect for all `resolutions` and `sizes`.

Comment: `background-size: contain`

Comment: have you tried "background-size": "contain" or "cover"

Comment: Both does not work...

Comment: Are you seeing this problem in mobile Safari? `background-size: cover` is a bit wonky in it. You may find [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari) helpful, if so.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the background-size from your slide, and let the .bcg class's background-size: `cover` work.  Cover will keep the aspect ratio, and resize the image so it is the smallest it can be while still covering the entire area.  `Contain` works similarly, but resizes it so one of the dimensions covers the entire area.

Answer (score 1):

`background-position: contain;` does work. However, you need to restructure your CSS a little in order for the percentages to work properly.

```
html, body, #slide-1, .bcg {
    height: 100%;
}

#slide-1 .bcg {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/1600/900') top center no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CPBy2/1/

---

Or if you actually need the DIV to scale 16:9 so other content with flow nicely on the page, you can do that as well with a padding trick.

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/1600/900') top center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#content:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

<div id="content"></div>Content after
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46A5R/

Comment: It works, but the height is never 100% in both the cases, when i re-size

Comment: So you want a 1600x900 div scaled to fit vertically? Or do you mean the image doesn't go the top and bottom due to the default margin/padding on HTML, and BODY tags?

Comment: you want a 1600x900 div scaled to fit vertically - yes

Comment: The only way I know to scale a div vertically is with Javascript. Since padding (even top and bottom padding) is based on the width of an element, not height, scaling a div based on the vertical height doesn't work with CSS. You could use background-size: cover; that might be what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/CPBy2/2/