# background-size: cover and iOS – we're not friends

Tags: ios, css, mobile, safari, background-size

I’m looking for a simple solution since hours, but I can’t find any. My problem: I have a site and i use background-size: cover to display the header picture in full size. It works fine on every browser, but it looks terrible on a iOS-Device.
Example: http://www.dnu-films.ch/site/
Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, looks fine when i resize my browser?

Comment: The background-size is not your problem. It seams the media styles in your css are wrong since also your menus dont collapse on mobile. You should fix that and then the background-size will not be an issue.

Comment: I found this thread maybe helps you
[CSS background-size: cover replacement for Mobile Safari][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari

Comment: @aaron: Try it on Safari on an iPhone - resizing isn't the same.

Comment: @Shinigami Thanks. Saw that thread, but it isn't a solution. The picture on big screen isn't centered and on mobile it doesn't show the whole image (as "cover" should do)...