# iOS Web App and Background-size

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, background-size

Our web app has a background image attached to its body, with background-size: cover. This works fine on iPad, but when adding the app to home screen, the background is removed.

Removing "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" helps, but we need this feature.

I can't seem to solve this, and would really love some inputs.

App: https://mementor.easydays.me

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari

Comment: I'd rather use background-size, because it works with out apple-mobile-web-app-capable. I think something else is the reason for this failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add the site to the home screen as a web app, and then click on the icon, the screen is white for a few seconds until the page loads, and then the background appears to load correctly.

The white background is used in place of a web app startup image, which you can specify like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">
```

I recommend looking into Apple's Startup Images ([more info on that here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)).

Does this solve your background image problem?

Comment: It actually works today. I must have had another error of some sort. Thank you.