# CSS background-image is not showing correctly on iPhone device (but works on Android and on chrome "iPhone view")

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

When viewing my site from a IOS device the background image is not showing correctly. It works flawlessy on other devices such as Android, PC and MAC web browsers.

I have set these CSS elements which came with the bootstrap template and tried different combinations:

```
#header {
background-image:url(../img/HS_16.jpg);
-webkit-background-size:;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:relative;
min-height: 512px; 
}
```

A bit hard to explain but if you go to http://holistiskasystrar.se from an IOS device and compare it to any other device, you see what i mean.

[Click her for example, Left is iPhone, right is chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af7jJ.jpg)

Comment: You'll probably get more answers to your question if you post images of what you're seeing on these different browsers. Just linking to an external website isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Safari is know to have buggy behaviour with background-size: cover; and background-attachment: fixed;

It is listed under the "Known Issues" Tab here: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

But there are a bunch of workarounds online, for example [CSS background-size: cover replacement for Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari/38532368#38532368)