# Iphone image zoom error css

Tags: css

I designed the web interface. It looks normal on the phone. The iPhone seems to be zoomed in as well. How can I fix.

I try -webkit-background-size:cover but it doesn't execute.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/css-background-size-cover-replacement-for-mobile-safari#21456799) might be helpful

Comment: Please elaborate more, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

add this meta to your head;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: the problem was'nt fixed