# Mobile background-size not working properly [html/css]

Tags: html, css, background, size, background-image

First off, I'd like to say that I have found this thread: ["background-size: cover" does not cover mobile screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659204/background-size-cover-does-not-cover-mobile-screen).
I have read through the responses in that thread and have tried them, to no avail.

Here is what the browser version of the site looks like:
[http://i.imgur.com/dmNWq.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/dmNWq.jpg)
And here is what the mobile version looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfvuX.png
(please bear with me, as I cannot post images due to having low rep.)

Relevant CSS:

```
.splash {
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url('../assets/splash.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-color: #159957;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Basically the problem is that the image won't correctly size on mobile, even with the correct overrides in place. I do not know what path to take, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about a link to your site? Or at least a working fiddle/codepen demo?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: 
`background: url('../assets/splash.png') no-repeat center center fixed;` 
you should use: 
 `background: url("../assets/splash.png") no-repeat fixed center center / cover;`

Why?
Because according to [W3](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference#Enhancements_in_CSS3) if you want to include the background-size value in the shorthand syntax, you need to:

> Explicitly include background-position values even if these are the same as the defaults (see above).
>   
> Write background-position values before background-size values.
>   
> Put a slash in between these two pairs of values because without it we cannot distinguish which values are for which