# Website background colour doesn't fill the screen mobile

Tags: html, css

When making my website I noticed that on a laptop/desktop its fine however when i look at it on mobile it leaves a big white gap at the bottom as the background colour doesn't stretch enough, when using it in portrait mode on my s8 the background doesn't cover the full screen

CSS:

```
html {
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
#background {
background-color: #ffff34;
background-size:     cover;                 
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
min-height: 1000px
}
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Yorkshire Sport 4 All</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <img style="padding-top:15px" src="images/logo2.jpg" alt="Logo 2">
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- start of body-->
            <div id="body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/sport1.jpg" alt="sport1">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/sport2.jpg" alt="sport2">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/sport3.jpg" alt="sport3">
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of body-->
            <!-- start of section-->
            <div id="section">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div style="font-size:16px; color:black;" class="body">

                            <p>
                                Here at Yorkshire Sport 4 All we provide fun and engaging sessions for children of all ages by Two Qualified P.E Teachers with a wealth of experience and an extensive knowledge
                                of primary and secondary P.E. curriculum<br />
                                What we offer:<br />
                            </p>
                            <ul>
                              <li>Elite Football Coaching In Schools<br />
                                    - An in depth knowledge of the game at all levels from semi professional to international <br />
                                    - Knowledge of the physiological characteristics of Elite football and how it can be implemented into coaching <br />
                                    - Planned coaching with a playing philosophy to suit your needs <br />
                                    - Position Specific coaching <br />
                                    - Performance Analysis <br />
                                    - Strength and conditioning <br />
                                    - Links with Professional and Semi Professional clubs in Lincolnshire and Yorkshire and Humber<br /></li>
                              <li>Term Time PPA cover in primary schools by qualifed teachers<br /></li>
                              <li>Wednesday Evening Football Club<br /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of section-->
            <div id="footer">
                <div>
                    <div class="header"> <a href="index.html"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <ul class="navigation">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="footnote"> &copy; Copyright &copy; 2017 Company name all rights reserved </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["background-size: cover" does not cover mobile screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659204/background-size-cover-does-not-cover-mobile-screen)

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well so we can see what the issue is?

Comment: added html to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply your background settings to the `body` element, not to anything else.

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffff34;
}
```

All the other background settings are superfluous, if you only use a background color and no image.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove these lines from css. It will not needed for coloured background.

```
background-size:     cover;                 
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

These are required when you are using image in background.